# Picture on title page

Tags: graphics, titles, koma-script

I'm trying to add a picture to my title page but the image appears on its own page. Can anyone help with this?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

 \title{Report}
 \author{blah}
 \date{\today}
 \publishers{blah}
 \nocite{*}
 \addbibresource{bib.bib}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{titlepage}
 \includegraphics{images/image.png}
 \maketitle

 \end{titlepage}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\maketitle` creates a specific titlepage layout. You can't combine it with other elements. But you can use `\titlehead` to insert a graphic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[width=6cm]{tiger}}
\title{Report}
\author{blah}
\date{\today}
\publishers{blah}
\begin{document}  
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have `titlehead` as an undefined control sequence, is it specific to `scartcl` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the `titling` package. With it you can access the `\title` `\author` and `\date` variables in the title page. This worked fine for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{The Lord of the Rings}
\author{John Tolkien}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage} %This starts the title page
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}\\ %Put the logo you want here
\begin{large}
My University \\ %The name your university
My Department\\
\end{large}
\vspace{4cm} %You can control the vertical distance
\begin{large} 
\textbf{\thetitle} \\
\end{large}
\theauthor\\
\vspace{7cm} %Put the distance you need.
\thedate
\end{center}
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

*I edited the `Large` environment I put.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that while they work, there are actually no fontsize environments like `\begin{Large}..\end{Large}` implemented (as environments), see [Do fontsize environments exist?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258277)

Answer (score 1):

Just put an image inside your title. Simple :)

You can add a \texttt for formatting the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{./images/ }

\title{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png} Here is my Title
}
\author{Saurabh Adhikary}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```