# How to prevent extra spaces when writing to .aux file?

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

Consider this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\csname mycommand\endcsname
\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\noexpand\mycommand{text}}
\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex` `.aux` is created:

```latex
\relax 
\gdef \mycommand {text}
```

Desired result is:

```latex
\relax 
\gdef\mycommand{text}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need it? The spaces don't matter. They're there to end the control sequence.

Comment: it doesn't work with environments. Example is `luacode*`. There has to be no spaces in `\end{luacode*}` but there is one.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `\string` command? `\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\mycommand{text}}` produces `\gdef\mycommand{text}`.

Comment: Writing environments to the aux sounds rather odd, but why should the space matter?

Comment: How should I know? I found this out through the logs. Anyway, it appears that I can't write `luacode*` environment inside a command definition (but `center` and others can be used). Although I can use multiple `\immediate\write\@auxout{}` to write on each line of `.aux` file, but the result is buggy (only works every 2nd time). Therefore, I think there is no easy way to do what I wanted (I should stick to other methods).

Comment: For `luacode*` You must put `\end{luacode*}` (with no spaces) on the newline for it to work. For example, `\begin {luacode*} variable = 68 \end{luacode*}` won't work but if newline is inserted (where I specified) then it will be a valid piece of code. Yes, if space is added after `\end` it will become again invalid. This is some very picky environment.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258277/do-fontsize-environments-exist, for example. Environment `foo` = `\foo` + `\endfoo`. But `luacode*` changing the catcode of \ implies 
looking for `\end{luacode*}` exactly. (Plus, the `*` parameter goes through an `\@ifstar` step; there is no `\endluacode*` command, as such.)

Comment: texdoc source2e: "\@ifstar {⟨YES⟩}{⟨NO⟩} Gobbles following spaces and then tests if next the character is a *. If it is, then it gobbles the * and expands to ⟨YES⟩, otherwise it expands to ⟨NO⟩." - in the section on defining commands, (`\newenvironment{foo}` becomes `\newcommand\foo{..}` and `\def\endfoo`; and `\newcommand` checks for *.)

Comment: There are defined macros `\luacodestar` and `\endluacodestart` but I don't know how can I use them directly (and if I should or able at all). In LuaTeX documentation, it is said that they can be used to define custom environments.

Comment: Environments will have pre- and post-code, and cleanup code, as well as the start and end macros.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to execute (Lua) code on the next run, but define it later in the document (back reference or something). I already wrote [the possible answer and my decision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668879/how-to-prevent-extra-spaces-when-writing-to-aux-file?noredirect=1#comment1662821_668879).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141399/discussion-between-cicada-and-andrew15-5).